# CakePHP 3 query all date in a date range from a table

Tags: cakephp, associations, query-builder, date-range, cakephp-3.x

I have a table called `Plans` which has column `period_from`, `period_to` which are date.

I have another table called `Prices` which has a column `date`. I wanna find out whether all the dates from `period_from` to `period_to` exists in the `Prices` table by matching with `date` column.

So far my code looks like this. The problem is it gives me result even if only one date in the date range exists.

```
$plans_table = TableRegistry::get('Plans');
$checkin = $this->request->data['checkin'];
$checkout = $this->request->data['checkout'];
$plans = $plans_table
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Prices' => function($q) {
            return $q->where([
                'Prices.date >=' => $checkin,
                'Prices.date <=' => $checkout
            ]);
        }
    ]);
```

CakePHP version 3.4.12

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting code, please make sure that it's readibly formatted, and that it's working (in terms of being valid syntax, unless that is the actual problem) - what you're showing is invalid syntax, which might confuse readers. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: what is the relationship between `Prices` and `Plans`? Also, can you please provide an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I was confused your question. Anyway, that may have your question. You want to find out between `period_from` and `period_to`. In that case, you can do something like that;

```
  'Prices.date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => [$checkin, $checkout]
```

If you want your `$checkin`,`$checkout` date are exactly the same with `$date`, I will do something like that;

```
  $dateArray = [$checkIn,$checkout]; //['yyyy-mm-dd','yyyy-mm-dd']
  ['Prices.date' => $dateArray] //meaning IN (checkin,checkout)
```

Hope your all `date` column data type are `date`. If data type is `datetime`, this code will not work. If I misunderstanding your question, do let me know. Will update answer for you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for adding the answer. What I am trying to achieve is all the dates between `$checkin` and `$checkout`. For example, if the `$checkin` date is 2017-08-15 and checkout date is 2017-08-17, I wanna make sure all the dates between this range (2017-08-15, 2017-08-16, 2017-08-17) exists in `Prices.date` column or not.